# How to dynamically append key/values to a nested object

Tags: javascript, data-structures, append, javascript-objects

I am trying to append to an object/dictionary of sorts that adds categories and subcategories as they are found. However, each time I try to add them it seems like I just get the last element added to the nested object and overwrites the previous additions. I've tried using `Object.assign()` and `{...obj, key:value}` to no avail.

I have multiple for-loops that independently add each key:value pair after the database has been queried.

I am looking to create an object resembling this:

```
{
  category1: {
    subcategory1: null,
    subcategory2: null,
    subcategory3: {
      microcategory1: null
    }
  },
  category2: {
    subcategory1: null,
    subcategory2: null,
    subcategory3: null
  }
}
```

But am getting this instead:

```
{
  cooking: {
    'ranges': null
  },
  sinks: {
    'filters': null
  }
}
```

There should be 10+ subcategories for both cooking and sinks.

This is the code as it stands:

```
let categoriesDictObj = {};

for (var index = 0; index < categories.length; index++) {
  let category = categories[index];

  const subCategories = await Product.find({
    productCategory: category,
  }).distinct("productSubCategory");

  for (
    var subCatIndex = 0; subCatIndex < subCategories.length; subCatIndex++
  ) {
    let subCategory = subCategories[subCatIndex];

    const microCategories = await Product.find({
      productMicroCategory: subCategory,
    }).distinct("productMicroCategory");


    // categoriesDictObj[category] = { [subCategory]: null };

    // Object.assign(categoriesDictObj, {
    //   [category]: { [subCategory]: null },
    // });

    categoriesDictObj = {
      ...categoriesDictObj,
      [category]: {
        [subCategory]: subCatIndex
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `[category]: { ...categoriesDictObj[category], [subCategory]: subCatIndex }` in the inner object, otherwise you're always overwriting the `category` object with a completely new one and only the last (with a single `subCategory` key) will prevail.

Comment: Why are you not using `microCategories` for anything?

Comment: @Bergi, microCategories dont exist yet but they will in future. I want to have it as a placeholder when additions can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to spread the previous `categoriesDictObj[category]` in the inner object, otherwise you're always overwriting the `category` object with a completely new one and only the last (with a single `subCategory` key) will prevail.

```
categoriesDictObj = {
  ...categoriesDictObj,
  [category]: {
    ...categoriesDictObj[category],
    [subCategory]: subCatIndex
  },
};
```

However, there's no need to make it that complicated. Just create the inner object, fill it in the inner loop, and then assign it as part of the `categoriesDictObj` in the outer loop:

```
const categories = …;
const categoriesDictObj = {};

for (let index = 0; index < categories.length; index++) {
  const category = categories[index];
  const subCategories = …;

  const subCategoriesDictObj = {};
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  for (let subCatIndex = 0; subCatIndex < subCategories.length; subCatIndex++) {
    const subCategory = subCategories[subCatIndex];
    const microCategories = …;

    subCategoriesDictObj[subCategory] = subCatIndex;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
  categoriesDictObj[category] = subCategoriesDictObj;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You could also make the variables mutable and keep the objects immutable by replacing the `subCategoriesDictObj[subCategory]` assignment with

```
subCategoriesDictObj = {
  ...subCategoriesDictObj,
  [subCategory]: subCatIndex
};
```

and the `categoriesDictObj[category]` asssignment with

```
categoriesDictObj = {
  ...categoriesDictObj,
  [category]: subCategoriesDictObj
};
```

but that's really just pointless inefficiency.